# c# OOD problem with generic collections and interfaces

Tags: c#, oop, generics, collections, interface

I'm trying to model a problem in a way that:

1. Schedule.Products collection could consist of both: IProducts and IProductsWithConfig
2. ProductWithConfig.Config collection could only consist of IProducts but not IProductsWithConfig

And I got a little stuck - as it is now (below) I cannot prevent IProductsWithConfig to be added/included in ProductWithConfig.Config. Any ideas how to code it in an elegant way?

```cs
    interface ISchedule
    {
        IEnumerable<IProduct> Products { get; set; }
    }

    interface IProductWithConfig : IProduct
    {
        IEnumerable<IProduct> Config { get; set; }
    }

    interface IProduct
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know how it would fit into your design, but if you had another interface that inherits `IProduct` - say `IPlainProduct` - then this would `is-a IProduct` but not `is-a IProductWithConfig`... and you could have `IEnumerable<IPlainProduct> Config { get; set; }`

Comment: @Fildor but IPlainProduct would be an empty interface that inherits from IProduct?

Comment: Could be. But there's no harm to that.

Comment: Actually, I think Point 2 violates Liskov Substitution Principle if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Basically the problem here is: You designed "having a config" implies "being a potential config element". But in your second requirement, you make "having a config" and "being a config" one-way exclusive. And thinking about this and my solution above: it may not even be enough. What if you have a class that implements both interfaces (which is totally legal)? ...

Comment: ... so, if you need to make sure a config element _has_ some properties, _but not others_ - that probably boils down to that your `Config` enumerable needs to be typed with a concrete sealed class. There is no other way I can think of that would prevent just creating another level o inheritance while implementing another interface, which could include having a config. And none of which is what you want, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of inheritance is that you can use any derived version of IProduct in any situation where you require IProduct. Every instance of a class that implements IProductWithConfig is by defintion an instance that implements IProduct. The comment that Fildor made makes sense: make the IProduct abstract and create a new descendant from it.

Or you could hide the public property Config and expose these via a few methods like Add(Product) and a read-only IEnumerable. Then you can control what kind of objects are added to the collection.

Comment: I was hoping that I could use some trick with co/contra-variance, which I'm not so familiar yet.

Comment: @adam.k contra or co variance just keeps you from assigning a `List<IDerivedFromIProduct>` to your `IEnumerable<IProduct>` but I can happily add an object to that enumerable as long as it `is-a` `IProduct`. That means somewhere up the tree it implements that interface.